# cmsms rss generation

Tags: content-management-system, rss2

I'm new to cmsms, i have installed a news module in it,now i have to create an rss for this news section, how can i generate an rss for my news section.
what are steps to display that generated rss in any of my page.

can any one guide me with correct path.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the CGFeedMaker module.  It already has a predefined template for the the News module, but you'll need to edit the values for name, copyright, etc.  Do that through Extensions >> Calguy's Feed Maker and pick the "news" feed.

Then, in your template, insert {CGFeedMaker action='autodiscovery' feed='news'} in between your head tags.

You *should* be good to go after that.